# Webflux Reactor how to merge Stream.map output, which can be Mono and Flux into Flux

Tags: spring-webflux, project-reactor

`A` is used to get source. In the following `map` function, source is a `Flux` if `a` owns source otherwise source is a `Mono`. Function returns all sources that can be queried based on List of A, list size could be 1. Question is how to handle this Mono and Flux combined to Flux, when Stream.map output could be either of both.

```
class A {
    String x;
    String y;
    boolean isOwner();
}

Flux<Source> foo(List<A> a) {
  Flux<Source> sources = a.stream().map(v -> if (v.isOwner) {
        Flux<Source> ownedSource = ...; return ownedSource;
      } else {
        Mono<Source> givenSource = ...; return givenSource;
      }
    }.???
  return sources;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it as a `Flux` with `flatMap`:

```
Flux<Source> foo(List<A> a) {
  Flux<Source> sources = Flux.fromIterable(a)
    .flatMap(v -> if (v.isOwner) {
        Flux<Source> ownedSource = ...; return ownedSource;
      } else {
        Mono<Source> givenSource = ...; return givenSource;
      }
    }
  return sources;
}
```

Comment: Much simpler than mine: `Stream.reduce(Flux::mergeWith)`

Comment: I general, I would suggest using only reactive components with connection to Reactor. Pairing with Streams may limit some optimizations otherwise available to native reactor components. You can always convert a stream to flux by `Flux.fromStream` and then use Reactive methods on it.